# Get MySQL error code with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using PHP and PDO to connect to my MySQL database. I configured the PDO connection so that I get any MySQL error thrown as an exception:

```
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Now lets suppose I execute a MySQL command that generates an error and I catch it, the error message is this:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Name' cannot be null

When I use `$exception->getCode()` it returns `23000`, which I think is from PHP or something. How do I get the specific MySQL error (`1048`) inside a catch block?

Comment: If u guys have any doubts about my question just ask. I dont know if its really possibe to do it. Do i have to code the error handling with SQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [PDOException](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php) object has a property `errorInfo` which is a three-element array, the same returned by `PDO::errorInfo()`.  The MySQL error code is element 1.

```
try {
    . . .
} catch (PDOException $e)
    $errorInfo = $e->errorInfo;
    error_log "MySQL error " . $errorInfo[1] . "\n";
}
```

PS: Note that just echoing the error is not proper exception handling, I'm just doing that to show how to access the info.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using PDO, you can refer to [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php), which provide an excellent description and example on how to get the error info from SQL.